# Service Fabric .NET Core 2.1 service communications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to get started on Service Fabric, and figuring out the best ways of using things. I figured I'd stick with using the new stuff, and tried to build a basic demo Service Fabric API. I'm using a stateless ASP Web API project to run my API. Behind that, I want to have a service layer in a separate project to keep my business logic. Since that would potentially have data such as a cache, I'm making my service layer an ASP.NET Core stateful project. The demo I was trying to follow from Pluralsight recommended using the remoting option because it was supposed to be the fastest way for Service Fabric services to talk with each other. After some digging trying to find out why I couldn't make the example I was looking at work, I found out that the demo was using .NET framework and remoting isn't supported in .NET Core.

Given that I'm trying to use .NET Core, what would be the best method of establishing connections between my services? My searches about how to do that pull up Microsoft docs, and the Service Fabric docs just bring up the shot gun approach, and it feels like a needle in a hay stack to find what I think should be very simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what links or examples you are referring to. It would be helpful to post those.

I have several .Net Core services running which are using the custom V2 serialization system all are able to communicate without issue.

However I am having issues with a .Net Framework service communicating with a .Net Core one however .Net Core to .Net Core works very well.

You can take a look at my simple system at this GitHub [link](https://github.com/Telavian/ServiceFabric.Serialization.V2).